# Detecting if a patch is applied or not

Tags: linux, makefile, patch

I am working on a project that requires me to patch 3rd party open source libraries for use in my application. To make things simple, I am only using Makefiles and a simple configuration script to build the application. I have multiple patches that I need to apply, so therefore I use Makefile dependencies to patch:

```
all: patch1 patch2 patch3
    do-build-stuff-here
patch1:
    patch -p0 < patch1.patch && touch patch1
patch2:
    patch -p0 < patch2.patch && touch patch2
patch3:
    patch -p0 < patch3.patch && touch patch3
```

I know about Quilt, which the Debian packaging system uses for maintainer patches. I've used it, and it really works. However, it introduces an unnecessary dependency, especially for those who don't have Debian.

Sometimes, not all the patches are applied to allow me (and other developers) retest the building and the application in certain conditions. When I call "clean" or "distclean", I usually reverse the patches:

```
clean: rmpatch1 rmpatch2 rmpatch3
    do-clean-stuff-here
rmpatch1:
    patch -p0 -R < patch1.patch
rmpatch2:
    patch -p0 -R < patch2.patch
rmpatch3:
    patch -p0 -R < patch3.patch
```

(Ignore the fact that I could just delete the original source and start fresh.)

However, patch will likely fail if patch #3 is not applied, and patch #1 and #2 are. Therefore, I depend on the patch counterparts for each rmpatch:

```
rmpatch1: patch1
    patch -p0 -R < patch1.patch
rmpatch2: patch2
    patch -p0 -R < patch2.patch
rmpatch3: patch3
    patch -p0 -R < patch3.patch
```

But this still doesn't solve my problem, and "make clean" ends up patching the source first, then unpatching again!

I guess my question would be: is there any way I can detect if a patch is applied or not? I know patch, when run interactively, will tell you that it found a previously applied patch. Can this behavior be reproduced non-interactively?

The other question (somewhat related) is whether or not this method of patching is valid, and if not, what method of sequential patching (via only Makefiles) I could use.

Comment: Patching is not the sort of thing that one should be doing in a makefile in the first place.

Comment: Where would it be done then? And even still, how would you detect if the patch was applied or not?

Comment: It should be done in the prep stage of the build tool, after the sources have been extracted. There is no way to determine if a patch has been applied other than to try to reverse it and see how much of it succeeded.

Comment: This is how it's setup in the Makefile - extract first, then patch. Building only occurs when the sources are all extracted and patched.

Answer (score 0):

You could cheat Makefile with something like this:

```
all: patch1 patch2 patch3
    do-build-stuff-here
patch1:
    patch -p0 < patch1.patch && touch patch1
    touch $@
patch2:
    patch -p0 < patch2.patch && touch patch2
    touch $@
patch3:
    patch -p0 < patch3.patch && touch patch3
    touch $@
```

This way a file for each rule will be created once the patch is applied. You can either test on its presence in the rules to unapply the patch, or have make use it to decide whether the patch needs to be reapplied.